# How to create broker as war file?

Tags: servlets, web-applications, war, activemq-artemis

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis, and I want to create a broker in war file to later deploy it on a Jetty server. However, I don't know how to configure Artemis to generate a war file.

Comment: There's not enough information to work with on this question.  What have you tried?  What were the results?  What tools (and versions) are you using?  Show your work.  Please review the ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't have any ability to generate a war file.

If you want to embed an instance of ActiveMQ Artemis in your web application you need to create your own war file and then add your class that creates the embedded broker instance.

For what it's worth, the broker ships with 2 examples of how to embed a broker instance using simple POJO configuration and also XML configuration. Those are in the `examples/features/standard/embedded` & `examples/features/standard/embedded-simple` respectively.